# I graduated high school vs. I graduated from high school?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

Which is proper?

> I graduated high school

or

> I graduated *from* high school

Comment: This may help: https://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/graduated-versus-graduated-from

Answer (score 2):

JacobIRR's link certainly goes over the rules well, but perhaps gets too snippy over right and wrong. It can't be overstated that language evolves with usage.

So if by proper you mean "following rapidly aging rules", *graduated from*. But if you mean "sounding correct to a native speaker", either one.